# Шаблонная функция. Ошибка C2760 синтаксическая ошибка: ожидался токен "<Нет данных>", а не "<Нет данных>"

Tags: c++, функции, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

Изучаю C++, дошёл до шаблонов функций - ради тренировки написал следующую программу (функция SortArray сортирует элементы полученного массива по возрастанию). При попытке выполнения выдаёт ошибку C2760 (программа не компилируется). Можете пояснить?
(пожалуйста, *подробно*, если мне что-то будет непонятно в объяснении, то я разберусь в процессе дальнейшего изучения).

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
template <typename t> void SortArray(t a[], const __int8 LENGTH)
{
    __int8 ielem;
    t elem;
    for (__int8 n = 0; n < LENGTH; n++)
    {
        for (__int8 n1 = n; n1 < LENGTH; n1++)
            if (a[n1] < a[ielem]) || (n1 == n) ielem = n1;
        elem = a[n];
        a[n] = a[ielem];
        a[ielem] = elem;
    }
}
int main()
{
    const __int8 A_SIZE = 10, B_SIZE = 5;
    float a[A_SIZE];
    int b[B_SIZE];
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ru");
    cout << "Введите элементы первого массива через пробел или через Enter:\n";
    for (__int8 i = 0; i < B_SIZE; i++)
        cin >> b[i];
    SortArray<int>(b, B_SIZE);
    cout << "Отсортированный по возрастанию массив:\n";
    for (__int8 n = 0; n < B_SIZE; n++)
        cout << b[n] << "  ";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Введите элементы второго массива через пробел или через Enter:\n";
    for (__int8 n = 0; n < A_SIZE; n++)
        cin >> a[n];
    SortArray<float>(a, A_SIZE);
    cout << "Отсортированный по возрастанию массив:\n";
    for (__int8 n = 0; n < A_SIZE; n++)
        cout << a[n] << "  ";
    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: У вас сама среда разработки ничего не подчёркивает?

Comment: Что такое `__int8` и почему вы "изучая С++" используете в своем коде этот странный тип, не имеющий никакого отношения к С++?

Comment: @Philippe Нет, ничего не подчёркивает.

Comment: @AnT Мне не нужен здесь больший тип.

Comment: Учтите, что меньший тип - не всегда лучше. Работа с байтами на современных процессорах медленнее, чем с `int`ами...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начнем с того, что вы забыли круглые скобки вокруг условия в `if` - не

```
if (a[n1] < a[ielem]) || (n1 == n) ielem = n1;
```

а

```
if ((a[n1] < a[ielem]) || (n1 == n)) ielem = n1;
```

Далее, вы используете не инициализированную переменную `ielem`. При *самой первой проверке* `a[n1] < a[ielem]` с чем сравнивается `a[n1]`? С каким элементом?

Это - то, что касается компиляции (синтаксиса). Что касается семантики - что делает ваша программа - то в этом смысле я ее не смотрел..

Кстати, не мало ли одного байта для размера массива?
И еще - если вы собираетесь использовать именно для объявленных массивов, как у вас в `main` - то я бы советовал сделать так:

```
template <typename t, size_t LENGTH>
void SortArray(t (&a)[LENGTH])
{
```

(дальше все, как у вас) - тогда длину массива компилятор выведет сам.

Comment: Ошибки исправил, спасибо (привык уже, что if работает и так, а переменные при объявлении сразу 0). Всё работает, большое спасибо. Почему он их мне не подчеркнул?..

Comment: Ну, я не знаю настройки вашей среды программирования, не подскажу...